# Click function in mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm looking for the mootools equivalent of the jquery way. I need to link a button click on clicking another button

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
   // execute some function
});
```

Comment: kick a shot to start the engine.

Comment: please explain what you really want, please provide more code where you are looking the equivalent for

Comment: `$('#myButton').click(function(){` would be `$('myButton').addEvent('click', function(){`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function callNewClick()
  {
    document.getElementById('btnTwo').click();
  }
  function helloUser()
  {
    alert('Hello!');
  }
</script>

<button id="btnFirst" onclick="callNewClick();"> ClickFirst </button>

<button id="btnTwo" onclick="helloUser();"> Hello </button>
```

For example, in your code:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
   document.getElementById('yourBtnTwoId').click();
});
```